# I keep getting an error message and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: lcd, temperature

I am using an Arduino Genuino, this is what comes up

```
Multiple libraries were found for "LiquidCrystal.h"
 Used: /home/user/Arduino/libraries/LiquidCrystal
 Not used: /opt/ArduinoIDE/libraries/LiquidCrystal
In file included from /home/user/Arduino/libraries/dht/DHT_U.cpp:22:0:
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/dht/DHT_U.h:25:29: fatal error: Adafruit_Sensor.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>

                             ^
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
```

Comment: what do you understand about what the message is telling you?

Answer (score 1):

The first notice about multiple libraries is not stopping you. The DHU library relies on the [Adafruit Unified Sensor Library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_DHT_Unified)

You should have the following libraries (installed and) included:

```
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>
```